# What is this spider found in day time?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image].

South India
Arm to arm about 3 inch in length. Day time. was hiding inside a cardboard storage box.

Answer (score -2):

It's definitely a species of Huntsman spider maybe of the genus "heteropoda" or "olios". Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 